# C#: Add if-else in Do - While condition

Tags: c#-4.0, do-while

How to add if-else condition in do while statement. If "responseStatus" is true I want to wait for 120secs else don't do anything with do-while and proceed with the next statement.

```
            bool responseStatus;

            do
            {
               //Do Something

               responseStatus = IsWaitingForStatus();

            } while (if(responseStatus) ? Thread.Sleep(120): do nothing)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what you want, but it sounds like you want to do this:

```
bool responseStatus;

// The first call should wait for a specified timeout
do
{
   responseStatus = IsWaitingForStatus();
   if(responseStatus)
       Thread.Sleep(120)
   else
       break;

} while (true);
```

Comment: It works! This is what I expected. Also, modified my question a bit.